# How to register a UPnP service

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, windows-ce, upnp

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project for Windows Mobile 6 ARMV4I where I would like to register a UPnP service.

I am using the Microsoft sample from the Windows CE 6 SDK as the implementation of the UPnP service. WINCE600\PUBLIC\SERVERS\SDK\SAMPLES\UPNP\DEVICE

Unfortunately, the `RegisterRunningDevice` call fails with the error E_HANDLE.

```
#include "upnpdevice_i.c"
#import "upnpdevice.dll" named_guids

int main()
{
    ::CoInitializeEx( NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED );

    using namespace UPnPHostLib;
    IUPnPDeviceControlPtr device_ctrl( CLSID_Device );
    IUPnPRegistrarPtr registrar( CLSID_UPnPRegistrar );

    bstr_t device_descr = /* contents of the device.xml file from the sample */

    // throws a _com_error exception where hr = E_HANDLE
    bstr_t device_id = registrar->RegisterRunningDevice( device_descr, 
        device_ctrl, 
        L"foo", 
        L"/windows/upnp", 
        0 );

    /* ... */

    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

I've seen others refer to this error during my web searches, but I have not seen any result.

- I have registered the upnpdevice.dll
- I have installed the "Optional Windows Mobile Server Components" upnpctrl, upnphost, and httpd.
- the executable, upnpdevice.dll, device.xml, and service.xml files are all in the `/windows/upnp` directory.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved it. The issue was that the [Optional Windows Mobile Server Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416384.aspx) weren't signed. When device.exe attempted to load them as stream drivers at boot time they were rejected.

-PaulH